# What is the Rose artifact referencing? It doesn't seem to be RWBY, like the final version?

Tags: one-step-from-eden-demo

The demo of *One Step From Eden* has a Rose artifact that has the flavor text of "Lovely" and has a design of a red heart symbol covered in circuitry.

[image]

Unlike the [Final Game's Rose](https://onestepfromeden.fandom.com/wiki/Rose), which is a rose flower and references the web animation series, RWBY, since that's its flavor text.

The Demo version doesn't seem to be referencing RWBY, as far as I can tell?

Is it referencing something else, like most flavor text in *One Step From Eden*? If so, what?

Answer (score 1):

"Lovely" might just be a reference to how roses are romantic, also reflected in how its image is a stylized heart symbol, with heart symbols being another "romantic", a.k.a "lovely" symbol.